# Cannot connect using ftp_connect()

Tags: php

I'm developing a web page using Microsoft WebMatrix and everything was going smoothly and working.
The problem I have is related to ftp_connect() in php.
I made several tests using this same program in my computer, but when I tried through the web page to make a file transfer, the ftp_connet() function did not work.
I've all ready searched and can't find a solution to this error, because I can connect with a ftp client, and have access through a webpage and can connect directly from my computer, but the not from the web.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  $conn_id = ftp_connect(FTPSERVER);
           $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, FTPUSER, FTPPASS);

       if(ftp_put($conn_id,$path_file_ftp_gr,$filegr_path,FTP_BINARY)) {
          if (ftp_put($conn_id,$path_file_ftp_pq,$filepq_path,FTP_BINARY)){
           $query_result = mysql_query($query_add);
           ftp_close($conn_id);
           echo 'Sucesso<br>';
           ftp_close($conn_id);
          }
       }
       else {
           echo 'falhou<br>';
       }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

You're not by chance passing an integer to the FTP port parameter are you? For me this doesn't work:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect('myserver.com',51);
```

But this does:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect('myserver.com','51');
```

Comment: I am not using a port number in the ftp_connect() function.

Comment: You're not doing something like prefixing the server with `ftp://` are you? It's just the domain or IP that's needed.

Comment: I have this:
define('FTPSERVER','www.magnistatus.pt');
define('FTPUSER','*****');
define('FTPPASS','*****');

Comment: Does `echo FTPSERVER;` output what you'd expect it to? Does `ftp_connect('www.magnistatus.pt');` work?

Comment: Do you have root access to the server running the web application? If so, can you connect to your FTP manually *from there*? (I'm wondering if FTP connections are blocked by firewall policy or something)

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what your're asking, but i can connect by ftp client (FileZila) and through the browser, but not through the website... I've allready been revising the wrintg and reading permissions for the ftp user and everything statys the same... I am sure that it is the connection that does not come through... I've all ready talked to the help-desk services of the server, but at the moment their services are down and I cant try to solve the problem in control panel...